# CS50 Pset 5 speller Seg fault

Tags: c, cs50

I get a Segmentation fault when I run it and I would really appreciate some pointer as to what I'm doing wrong.

For those who see this outside of the cs50 tag, I am trying to load a dictionary (in load), compare a string to a word from the dictionary (in check), and unload the dictionary (in unload).

This is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"
#define HASH_MAX 27

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

node *hashtable[HASH_MAX];
int count = 0;


int hash(string word)
{
    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        num += word[i];
    }
    return num % HASH_MAX;
}

bool check(const char *word)
{
    char WordCopy[strlen(word) + 1];
    strcpy(WordCopy, word);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(WordCopy); i++)
    {
        tolower(WordCopy[i]);
    }

    node *cursor = hashtable[hash(WordCopy)];
    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(cursor -> word,WordCopy) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor -> next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    node *head = hashtable[0];
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    string word = NULL;
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        if(new_node == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(new_node -> word, word);

            new_node -> next = head;

            head = hashtable[hash(new_node -> word)];
        }
        fclose(file);

        count++;
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return count;
}
/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool unload(void)
{
    node *head = hashtable[0];
    node *cursor = head;

    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor -> next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The hashtable consists of 27 linked lists. So any time you interact with the hashtable, you need to compute the `hash` function before you can retrieve the appropriate `head` pointer. In the `unload` function, you need to destroy 27 linked lists, not just one. The `load` function needs a lot of work. One possible cause for the segfault is that `fopen` fails and returns `NULL`. You need to check `if (file == NULL)` after calling `fopen`, and handle the error if it is `NULL`.

Comment: So the head isn't pointing to the first linked list?

Comment: The code in the `check` function is what I expect to see. You compute the hash and get the first node in the linked list from the hashtable. And then you use the pointer to traverse the list. But in `load`, you aren't doing anything useful at all with the variable called `head`. And in `unload`, the variable `head` gets the pointer from the first linked list, and is used to free the items of that list. But there are 26 more lists that need to be freed.

Comment: Ok, thanks that's really helpful, I found the way they explained it in the videos kinda useless

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!.  There are 3 warnings produced: 
untitled2.c: In function ‘check’:
untitled2.c:41:22: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for(int i = 0; i < strlen(WordCopy); i++)
                      ^
untitled2.c:43:9: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
         tolower(WordCopy[i]);
         ^
untitled2.c: In function ‘size’:
untitled2.c:105:12: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
     return count;
 (cont

Comment: (cont)  I compiled the posted code under linux.  Using the following compiler options. `gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra  -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic`  If your using a different compiler, the options will be different.